# Why is component not connecting to the redux store?

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to connect some component (USERS) to my store. I will show you each step.

First of all i create my store in index.js:

```
// composeWithDevTools helps to follow state changes, remove in production
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)));
//sagaMiddleware.run(usersSaga);
console.log('MYSTORE: ', store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

My reducer is coded in the following way:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import usersReducer from './usersReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    users: usersReducer,
});
```

Now my App.js file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthorisationMails } from './route-components/AuthorisationMails.js';
import { ChangePassword } from './route-components/ChangePassword.js';
import { Credits } from './route-components/Credits.js';
import { Graphs } from './route-components/Graphs.js';
import { Groups } from './route-components/Groups.js';
import { HeaderBar } from './components/HeaderBar.js';
import { Home } from './route-components/Home.js';
import { Login } from './route-components/Login.js';
import { MailServers } from './route-components/MailServers.js';
import { MailStatus } from './route-components/MailStatus.js';
import { Options } from './route-components/Options.js';
import { StatusMails } from './route-components/StatusMails.js';
import { Users } from './route-components/Users.js';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <HashRouter>
            <HeaderBar />
            <Route path="/">
                <Redirect to="/login" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/dashboard_user" component={Users} />
        </HashRouter>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

In Users, i try to connect to the store with a mapstateToProps and connect as you see here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../redux/actions';

export class Users extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('USERPROPS: ', this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>Users</div>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('USERSSTATE: ', state.user);
    return {
        users: state.userReducer,
    };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Users));
```

The problem here is that somehow i am connecting in the wrong way, since the console.log of USERPROPS does not contain a property user. It contains history location and match.

I tried connecting by using the following url https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect.

Any idea on why my component is not connecting to the store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it, i removed the brackets when importing components, thus for example:

import { Credits } from './route-components/Credits.js' => import Credits from './route-components/Credits.js'

Comment: Yes Exactly, You have to export the component as default.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might need to use state.users.user:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users.user,
    };
};
```

Comment: this should not make any difference since i would still see the userReducer in my console.log of the properties.

Comment: Is your console.log of state.user null in mapStateToProps?  Try logging state.userReducer

Comment: yes i am mapping state.user in console.log, but it is not even printing:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('USERSSTATE: ', state.userReducer);
    return {
        users: state.userReducer.user,
    };
};
```

Comment: Try console.log('USERSSTATE: ', state.users.user);     userReducer is renamed to users in the combineReducers step.  Or just start with console.log('USERSSTATE: ', state.users); and see if that works

Comment: treid that too, if those variables would exits, the console statement should return null so it seems like it does not even get there.

Comment: How about logging just state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199438/discussion-between-bottomsnap-and-kees-til).